# Type deduction when using a templated lambda with a nested struct + analyzing possibly unused assembly output

Tags: c++, templates, assembly, lambda, c++14

I have the following code that I can compile successfully on GCC (6.2), Clang (3.9) and MSVC (2017RC)

```
template<typename T>    // (A)
  auto asdf = [](T x) {
      struct foo {
        T xyz;
      };

      return foo{x};
    };


int main() {
  return asdf<float>(3.14).xyz; // (B)
}
```

I have a few questions regarding the above code:

1. Why does this fails to compile on GCC 5.4 with the error:
   `error: use of 'asdf<float>' before deduction of 'auto'` on line (A)
2. The assembly generated by GCC & MSVC (and Clang to an extent) is basically `mov eax, 3; ret;` However Clang produces some extra guards, what is the significance of the check and when can/will the check be hit:

Clang output:

```
main: # @main
    mov     eax, 3
    ret

    cmp     byte ptr [rip + guard variable for asdf<float>], 0
    jne     .LBB1_2
    mov     qword ptr [rip + guard variable for asdf<float>], 1
.LBB1_2:
    ret

asdf<float>:
  ;empty
guard variable for asdf<float>:
  ;empty
```

3. And lastly, I know that asdf is a variable template however given the lambda is there any way to automatically deduce the template arguments in this case on line (B), assuming I'm using a dependent type from **T**?

Link on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/xX5d0d)

Comment: Your whole example is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: 1. GCC bug. 2. This looks like an attempt to ensure that `asdf<float>` isn't initialized twice; of course, since the initialization here is a no-op it's rather pointless. File a bug with clang. 3. No. If you want deduction, use a generic lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the extra asm from clang is *after* the RET instruction, and there are no branches to it from before the RET.  Thus, it is not part of the preceding function.  **clang's `main()` is identical to gcc's `main()`**

The other clue to that fact is the blank line before it.

What's really going on is that the Godbolt Javascript or server-side stuff (not sure where this happens) has erroneously removed a label that it shouldn't have.  Click the `.LX0` button to disable removal of unused labels, and you'll see (with actually irrelevant labels removed manually):

```
main:                                   # @main
        mov     eax, 3
        ret

__cxx_global_var_init:                  # @__cxx_global_var_init
.Lfunc_begin1:
        cmp     byte ptr [rip + guard variable for asdf<float>], 0
        jne     .LBB1_2
        mov     qword ptr [rip + guard variable for asdf<float>], 1
.LBB1_2:
        ret
```

---

The guard variable does really exist though :(

```
asdf<float>:
    .zero   1
    .size   asdf<float>, 1

    .type   guard variable for asdf<float>,@object    # @guard variable for asdf<float>
    .section        .bss._ZGV4asdfIfE,"aGw",@nobits,asdf<float>,comdat
    .weak   guard variable for asdf<float>
    .p2align        3
guard variable for asdf<float>:
    .quad   0                       # 0x0
    .size   guard variable for asdf<float>, 8
```

It looks like Matt's code is accidentally filtering [`.zero`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Zero.html#Zero) and `.quad` directives now, too, since the `asdf<float>:` label shows up, but its `.zero 1` doesn't.

I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/gcc-explorer/issues/192) on the github page for the code that powers the site.  Matt Godbolt is usually pretty quick to take a look at stuff.  :)

Anyway, so there is wasted code with clang, but it runs only at startup, and is in the `.text.startup` section along with other "cold" stuff.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry for the confusion: I've now fixed this issue so hopefully you won't be confused by the apparently extraneous initializer code sans label. It will now show up with the `__cxx_global_var_init` label, which should help explain!

Comment: @MattG: Thanks, Matt.  Keep up the good work :)  Oh, forgot to mention in my bug report that the clang output seems to be missing the `.zero` after the `asdf<float>` label, and the `.quad` after the guard variable.  It doesn't *always* filter those directives, but it does in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this fails to compile on GCC 5.4 with the error:error: use of 'asdf' before deduction of 'auto' on line (A)

Likely a bug, compilers can be affected from bugs as any other piece of software.

> And lastly, I know that asdf is a variable template however given the lambda is there any way to automatically deduce the template arguments in this case on line (B)?

Since C++14, you can use a generic lambda to do that:

```
auto asdf = [](auto x) {
    struct foo {
        decltype(x) xyz;
    };

    return foo{x};
};

int main() {
    return asdf(3.14).xyz;
}
```

---

> The assembly generated by GCC & MSVC (and Clang to an extent) is basically mov eax, 3; ret; However Clang produces some extra guards, what is the significance of the check and when can/will the check be hit

I'm not an expert, so I cannot say for sure.
Anyway, I suspect this code can be safely removed, for it is useless from the point of view of the firsts instructions.
The `mov` is the optimized version of your code and that's all, `asdf<float>` is no longer required.